# Python, Flask, SqlAlchemy - join itself and manipulate results

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have following model

```
class Deals(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'deals'

    id = db.Column(db.Unicode(32), primary_key=True)
    contract_length = db.Column(db.Integer)  
    device_price = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=6, scale=2)) 
    monthly_price = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=6, scale=2)) 
    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('devices.id'))
    device_color_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

At one point I run

```
results = Deals.query.join(Phone, Deals.device).group_by(Deals.contract_length, Deals.device_price, Deals.monthly_price, Deals.device_id)
deals_p = results.paginate(page, per_page=limit)
```

The reason for group by is that we have the same deal for different device variants (colors) spread accross different rows (deal IDs). 
What I need to do is to add other variants to results. This could be achieved by executing sql below in a loop and adding extra attribute to each contract.

```
Select c.*
From deals as d
Join deals as d1
On d.contract_length = d1.contract_length
And d.device_price = d1.device_price
And d.monthly_price = d1.monthly_price
And d.device_id = d1.device_id
And c.device_color_id <> c1.device_color_id
Where c1.id = ::ID
```

Any clue how to achieve this in flask, sqlalchemy?